# Google-Apps-Script gadget in Sites inconsistent on iOS device

Tags: mobile, user-interface, google-apps-script

I am creating UI in Google Sites by inserting a google apps script Gadget.  Things work well on my desktop, but when I access the site on my iPhone or iPad, then I get intermittent UI behavior.  That is, my buttons or text boxes do not respond every time these are touched.
I have broken this down to the basic code for my script, below, and still see this.
Thanks for your time - Larry King

```
    function doGet() {
      var eventApp = UiApp.createApplication();
      var eventIDBox = eventApp.createTextBox();
      var eventButton = eventApp.createButton("Submit");      
      var eventLabel = eventApp.createLabel("Welcome").setVisible(false);
      var eventHandler = eventApp.createClientHandler().forTargets(eventLabel).setVisible(true);
      eventButton.addClickHandler(eventHandler);
      eventApp.add(eventIDBox).add(eventButton).add(eventLabel);
      return eventApp;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens because in iOS, the first tap goes in selecting the iFrame housing the UI and the second goes to the actual UI control. This is a known issue and is recorded in [Issue 1086](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=1086). Please star the issue to register your interest for a solution.

Comment: Thanks Srik.  Seems like that makes GAS UI pretty much a show-stopper, at least for mobile.  Maybe that, along with other reasons, is why UI under Script Services Reference is shown as experimental.  It will be interesting to see Google Web Designer when it is available.  I am new to this, but my gut feel is the Google UI tools are not very advanced.  Thanks again.  Larry